# Phonegap 2.7.0 on Android doesn't open external links in default browser

Tags: javascript, cordova, sencha-touch-2, external-links

I'm developing and iOS/Android application with Sencha Touch 2 and Phonegap 2.7.0. I'm trying to make a JS function that would open a given url in device default browser.

`window.open(link, '_system');` works just fine for iOS, but neither this, nor any other ways work for Android. It either opens a link inside the app (instead of content), or doesn't open it at all.

I have `<access origin=".*"/>`; inside config.xml (tried different ways, none works).

Is there any way to make it work?

Comment: have you tried adding `target='_blank'` to your links?

Comment: The solution is not a programming solution so is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my mistake: I've accidentally copied iOS's cordova.js file into Android's project.